# ibeacons Technology from Microsoft

Tags: ibeacon

I just come across about ibeacons technology which introduced by Apple but haven't got any API/framework from Microsoft.

Is there any API or framework available from Microsoft which gives support for Ibeacons implementation?

Thanks

Comment: There's actually no API in android for interpreting iBeacon advertising packets specifically, but the Android BLE apis will give you the advertising packets which you can decode yourself.  Probably the place to start would be to look into the state of BLE support on your specific Microsoft platforms of interest.

Comment: As Chris notes, Android has no native support, which is why I wrote the Android iBeacon Library, which is open source, and could serve as a model for a Microsoft library.  I have not done any Microsoft development, but if there is a BluetoothLE API, this could be ported without huge effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with Windows Phone 8, because it only supports [Bluetooth 3.1](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/start/bluetooth-faq)  iBeacons require Bluetooth 4.0, also known as BluetoothLE.

In October 2013, [Nokia announced](http://www.nokia.com/us-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142060) that upcoming phones would have Bluetooth LE support.  Unfortunately, these only allow OS-level pairing with Bluetooth LE devices.  [There is no public api.](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Introduction_to_Bluetooth_support_on_Windows_Phone_8)

This makes it impossible to develop a third-party iBeacon Library for the Windows Phone similar to the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/).

Unfortunately, Windows Phone users will have to wait for a later release with either native iBeacon support or a public BluetoothLE API that allows a third party to develop a Windows iBeacon Library.

**Update: this appears to remain impossible with Windows Phone 8.1.  See my comment on the answer from @keni**

Comment: With regards to your response to @keni's answer, does this mean that it is completely impossible using the public APIs to communicate with an iBeacon, even if its UUID is known beforehand?

Comment: I would like a second opinion from a Windows Phone developer before I make this conclusion, because I am not experienced on this platform.  I looked over the new APIs, and I do not see anything that allows you to access the raw BLE advertisement packet like on Android, OSX Maverticks, or Linux, the three platforms that allow scanning for iBeacons in user code.  If a Windows Phone developer can confirm there are no public APIs to access this raw advertisement data, then it is impossible.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-519 - at about 8:00 the developers make fairly clear that this is a feature that they will be supporting but are not doing so yet.

Comment: Looks like Windows 10 may integrate it: http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-10-will-support-ibeacon-technology/

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Windows 10 will support Bluetooth LE Advertisements. Current status as of today (4/23/2015) is that the preview build of Windows 10 still has an incomplete SDK implementation and a few bugs. However, next week a new build will be introduced and it can be safely assumed that we'll get a good glimpse on how this will actually work.

Sending and receiving pure Advertisements works already. Have a look at the Sample that you can download from github here:https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/bluetoothadvertisement

Answer (score 0):

Update

a public BluetoothLE API will come in Window Phone 8.1

http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/19234_Windows_Phone_81_receives_Blue.php

Comment: From what I can see there is no way to get access to arbitrary advertisement data needed to look for iBeacons.  The public API to look for a Bluetooth 4 device requires you to specify it beforehand: 
    var themometerServices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration
        .DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService
            .GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(
                GattServiceUuids.HealthThermometer),
        null);

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following blog post for BLE for developers in Windows 8.1 
http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2014/02/ble-for-windows-81-part-i.html